# How can I enable the creation and editing of hyperlinks in shared Excel worksheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, spreadsheet

I have hyperlinks in some Excel 2010 (both .xlsx and .xls formats) worksheets.  If I enable sharing of the workbook I can no longer edit or create hyperlinks - the options no longer exist on the menu and/or are greyed out.

How can I fix and/or workaround this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem and fixed by using the =HYPERLINK function in the cell rather than the "insert hyperlink" option.

```
HYPERLINK(link_location, [friendly_name])
```

Make sure to place the location and friendly_name in quotes (" ").

Answer (score 3):

Sharing a workbook disables several features in Excel.Hyperlinks, merged cells, charts, pictures and more. If the workbook is shared, you will not be able to use these features. If you un-share the workbook, these items should be availble again. 
This has been the case for a long time. [This Excel 2003 article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/about-shared-workbooks-HP005262294.aspx?CTT=1)  shows this, and [this Excel 2010 article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/overview-of-sharing-and-collaborating-on-excel-data-HA010342753.aspx?CTT=1)  also shows this.

Answer (score 3):

I can get around this by copying the hyperlink from a nonshared Excel file and pasting it into the shared Excel file.

This is not ideal and more work but could be helpful if you dont want to continually share and unshare.

Answer (score 1):

CharlieRB's suggestion didn't work for me, I needed to insert a # to get the hyperlink to work:

```
=HYPERLINK("#'Sheet3'!A1","Click here to go to Sheet3, A1")
```